# DB2: Using DATE Functions to get Month or Day names in another Language (German)

Tags: sql, db2

I want to build a Time Dimension in a Data Warehouse. Some fileds should show the name of the month or the week. With the Functions `TO_CHAR(loaddate,'MONTH')`
or `TO_CHAR(loaddate,'DAY')` I do get the names, but they are in English. In my case I need them in German.

Is there a way to get them directly in the necessary language or do I have to work with CASE and translate it in a custom function?

Thanks

```
TO_CHAR(loaddate,'MONTH')
```

Returns JANUARY expected JANUAR

```
TO_CHAR(loaddate,'DAY')
```

Returns Monday expected Montag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting special register CURRENT LOCALE LC_TIME appropriately before running the SQL.

[Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053732.html)

The supported locale names are listed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/c0052657.html). For example de_DE or de_CH.

Here is an example, using the command line, and you can also set the special register on the fly, or inside stored procedures:

```
$ db2 "values monthname(current date)"

1                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
February                                                                                            

  1 record(s) selected.

$db2 "set current locale lc_time = 'de_DE'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "values monthname(current date)"

1                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Februar                                                                                             

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned, that I'm using a procedure. Is it possible to use SET CURRENT LOCALE LC_TIME = 'de_DE' in a stored procedure? Thx!

Comment: I keep getting: 
MUX.TIME_DIM: 30: No authorized routine named "CHAR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.18.60
No authorized routine named "CHAR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.18.60
I have added the line as suggested.

Comment: As I was trying some other things, I accidently delted some signs. The error I was getting has nothing to do with this issue. Now it works perfect. Tanks a lot =)